# Downlaod plotly waterfall chart as pdf does not work within shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, download, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

Im trying to download the following waterfall chart created inside a shiny dashboard as a pdf but when I use the `shinydashboard` interface I download an empty pdf.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    downloadButton('downloadPlot', 'Download Plot')
  ),
  dashboardBody(plotlyOutput('pl'))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  plotInput <- function(){
    x= list("Sales", "Consulting", "Net revenue", "Purchases", "Other expenses", "Profit before tax")
    measure= c("relative", "relative", "total", "relative", "relative", "total")
    text= c("+60", "+80", "", "-40", "-20", "Total")
    y= c(60, 80, 0, -40, -20, 0)
    data = data.frame(x=factor(x,levels=x),measure,text,y)
    
    fig <- plot_ly(
      data, name = "20", type = "waterfall", measure = ~measure,
      x = ~x, textposition = "outside", y= ~y, text =~text,
      connector = list(line = list(color= "rgb(63, 63, 63)"))) 
    fig <- fig %>%
      layout(title = "Profit and loss statement 2018",
             xaxis = list(title = ""),
             yaxis = list(title = ""),
             autosize = TRUE,
             showlegend = TRUE,waterfallgap = "0.8")
    
    fig
  }
      
  
  
      output$pl<-renderPlotly({
        plotInput()
      })

      output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "Shinyplot.pdf",
        content = function(file) {
          pdf(file)
          plotInput()
          dev.off()
        })  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotly is not standard R graphics. You can't use dev to capture it. Try this:

```r
    output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "Shinyplot.pdf",
        content = function(file) {
            plotly::export(plotInput(), file)
    })
```

Use `plotly::export` to capture

Note: `export` is in the process of being deprecated (use `orca` instead). `orca` needs to install some [extra system dependencies](https://github.com/plotly/orca).

Usage is similar: `orca(plotInput(), file = file)`

Comment: How can I force using plotly::export if I dont weant to install orca

Comment: Just use `plotly::export` then. It is working. The message is just to let you know it will not work one day and you should prepare to switch to `plotly::orca`

Comment: i get an empty  white pdf

Comment: I don't know your system information, `plotly::export` worked fine on my end and it should work on other machines as well. Maybe you are missing something, I can't tell

Comment: in rstudio cloud it does not work as well

Comment: I just tried in Rstudio, no problem at all. It has to be your browser problem. Make sure you use the latest browser, like Chrome or Firefox, turn off some browser extension that  will block javascripts

Comment: I dont know what can block javascripts but it does not work in both of them